# Git mergetool performance

Tags: git, git-merge, mergetool

The git `mergetool` command performance seems pretty slow especially in comparison to hg `merge`.  Is this a documented issue?  Are there any ways to speed it up?

We spend a lot of time waiting for each file differences to be presented when running the command.

Comment: mergetool is shell so it's not going to be super fast. That said, the execution time of mergetool is likely to be dwarfed by the time spent to actually merge conflicts in your chosen merge tool. Which tool are you using? Are you sure that it's not the startup cost of this tool that you are paying?

Comment: Which mergetool are you using?  My guess would be that launching the external tool is slow, not git assembling the command line.

Comment: We're using Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe.

Comment: Similarly the difftool is slow as well using Beyond Compare as well.  We use the same thing with HG and it's much faster.  As you've pointed out must be the way in which git repeatedly invokes the tools.

Answer (score 1):

That should improve with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019, five years later) because "`git mergetool`" and its tests now spawn **fewer** subprocesses.

See [commit 7e6d6f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e6d6f7610965906d071022615bf64f14c60c0d2), [commit 8b01465](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b014655105e27d44cf62f61dd6b24322a57048f), [commit e10dffd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e10dffd067002ea83c5293c9440adc5f23825110) (12 Jun 2019), and [commit b4a04c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4a04c8f7c4f98dd335dc5ee00059bcd6cfc8b53) (10 Jun 2019) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2950cbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2950cbd4999e230c985be9f2b40cc0bf787fbdd3), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `mergetool`: use shell variable magic instead of `awk`
>
> `git-mergetool` spawns an enormous amount of processes.
>
> For this reason, the test script, `t7610`, is exceptionally slow, in particular, on
>   Windows.
>   Most of the processes are invocations of `git`. There are also some that can be replaced with shell builtins.
>   Avoid repeated calls of `git ls-files` and `awk`.